# Typescript import different functions

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I am using the Observable class and have the following

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Now I want to use the .of function of Observable, therefore I have to add the following into my imports

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

My question is, why do I have to import these functions separately.  Shouldn't this be part of the Observable class?  Plus when I navigate into the rxjs module folder I see a number of different files such as of.d.ts, merge.d.ts.  Why are these in separate files, is it to minimize the files loaded?  Plus how do I load the complete library if I want to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's to allow you to keep your library footprint as small as possible. If you want to drag everything in, you can reference the Rx.d.ts file. However, I've found that targeting only what I'm using is saving me over 100K uglified js in rxjs alone, so I've created my own "barrel" for the task. Here's a sample:

```
export { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
export { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
export { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
export { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
export { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/never';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/using';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/zip';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/concat';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/pairwise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/zip';
```

Note that the files in `observable` are the static methods you want to be able to call on Observable, and those in `operator` are those available on Observable instances.

Comment: Another one quite common: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`